# Zonal Statistics in QGIS

Tags: qgis, classification, zonal-statistics, land-cover

I am using raster layer zonal statistics in QGIS. I want to quantify the water yield contribution of each LULC class, but the results of the zonal statistics is greater than the value given by the model I am using. The layers I am using are also of the same resolution. I was wondering if this is a limitation of QGIS or if there is a method that can help me attain a more accurate value?

Comment: Can you provide your data? If not maybe, add some screenshots to see your data